# Multiple authors in Rmarkdown ioslides_presentation without Hyphen sign

Tags: r-markdown

I want to add two authors in my Rmarkdown presentation using [ioslides_presentation](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/ioslides-presentation.html) as the output. This is what I tried:

```
---
title: "Sample title"
author: 
  - "Author1"
  - "Author2"
output: ioslides_presentation
---
```

However it gives me an extra Hyphen sign for both authors: [image]

If I change the output to [slidy_presentation](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/slidy-presentation.html) or [revealjs::revealjs_presentation](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/revealjs.html) it'll work fine. It's only the problem with *ioslides_presentation*.
Any help is appreciated.